# The parshanut-torah-comment tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

It seems to me that this tag needs sorting out, because the wiki explanation of this tag is very vague and unclear, and there seems to be no consensus as to its correct application - yesterday I added it to two questions, somebody approved the edits, and later somebody removed them.

So either it has to made very clear when and when not to use it, or alternatively - and this gets my vote - to remove it altogether, because it does not seem to be very useful since the parsha tags alone should be adequate.

What does the community think?

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/445; see especially its answers.

Comment: I'm starting to think that we should kill this tag.  Most questions asking about a text are asking for broader interpretations (not limited to *only* the p'shat meaning of the words, or close reading), and if we want to call out that subset of questions we should perhaps call the tag something like "pshat-close-reading".  Just a comment because I haven't surveyed the questions to assess the impact.